# Can 1D CNNs infer a feature from two other included features?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, feature-extraction, feature-selection, conv-neural-network

I'm using a 1D CNN on temporal data. Let's say that I have two features A and B. The ratio between A and B (i.e. A/B) is important - let's call this feature C. I'm wondering if I need to explicitly calculate and include feature C, or can the CNN theoretically infer feature C from the given features A and B?

I understand that in deep learning, it's best to exclude highly-correlated features (such as feature C), but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO. Using the standard DNN layers will not automatically capture this `A/B` relationship, because standard layers like `Conv/Dense` will only perform the matrix multiplication operations.

To simplify the discussion, let us assume that your input feature is two-dimensional, where the first dimension is `A` and the second is `B`. Applying a `Conv` layer to this feature simply learns a weight matrix `w` and bias `b`

y = w * [f_A, f_B] + b = w_A * f_A + w_B * f_B + b

As you can see, there is no way for this representation to mimic or even approximate the ratio operation between `A` and `B`.

You don't have to use the feature `C` in the same way as feature `A` and `B`. Instead, it may be a better idea to keep feature `C` as an individual input, because its dynamic range may be very different from those of `A` and `B`. This means that you can have a multiple-input network, where each input has its own feature extraction layers and the resulting features from both inputs can be concatenated together to predict your target.

Comment: Very interesting point about the multiple input network. Do you have any suggestions for how to group features together to create the different inputs? In my data, I have thousands of features that we can categorize as 1) raw data, 2) data that was calculated from the raw data (e.g. ratios), 3) percent changes of the data

Comment: What you are talking about is in the scope of feature engineering. Thus, you don't know which one works the best in advance, but you can try all of them and make an ensemble model if you want.